# ¿Cómo funciona sizeof() de C++?

Tags: c++, array, bucle-for

he estado practicando con los array en C++ y he probado de iterar uno con un bucle for.

Con explicaciones de varios sitios, he conseguido iterarlo y que salga exactamente en la consola como quería. El código es el siguiente:

```
string colores[5] = {"negro", "amarillo", "lila", "blanco", "azul"};

for (int i = 0; i <= sizeof(colores) / sizeof(colores[0]) - 1; i++) {
        cout << i + 1 << " - " << colores[i] << "." << endl;
}
```

La salida en consola es la siguiente:
1 - negro.
2 - amarillo.
3 - lila.
4 - blanco.
5 - azul.

La pregunta aquí es, ¿cómo funciona exactamente esto: sizeof(colores) / sizeof(colores[0]) - 1?

En mi lógica de otros lenguajes, dejaría sizeof(colores) - 1 para que no apareciera en la consola la sexta línea (por lo de que se cuenta a partir del cero):
6 -

Si lo dejo así, me aparece esta sexta línea:

1 - negro.
2 - amarillo.
3 - lila.
4 - blanco.
5 - azul.
6 -

He leído que sizeof() devuelve el tamaño del objeto en bytes. Por eso, después se tiene que dividir ese número de bytes con el tamaño del elemento. Es esto lo que no acabo de entender. ¿Alguien me podría dar una explicación, si no más sencilla, más detallada?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> He leído que `sizeof()` devuelve el tamaño del objeto en bytes.

[Correcto](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sizeof).

> Por eso, después se tiene que dividir ese número de bytes con el tamaño del elemento. Es esto lo que no acabo de entender.

`sizeof(colores)` te regresara:

```
tamaño de std::string * cantidad de elementos
```

Si tu quieres obtener la cantidad de elementos, lo lógico seria que lo dividieras por el tamaño de `std::string`. Y como los elementos de `colores` son strings, lo mas sencillo es dividirlo por `sizeof(colores[0])`.

---

Como una nota, si estas usando C++, lo correcto seria usar [`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array). Este te da varias funciones utilitarias, entre ellas `size()` que te da el tamaño. Tu codigo se simplificaria a:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <array>

int main(int /*argc*/, char * /*argv*/[]) {
    std::array<std::string, 5> colores = {"negro", "amarillo", "lila", "blanco", "azul"};

    for (int i = 0; i < colores.size(); i++) {
        std::cout << i + 1 << " - " << colores[i] << "." << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Genial, me has ayudado mucho. ¡Muchas gracias! Aún me queda mucho que aprender de C++ :). Eso es lo más divertido.

Answer (score 1):

Buen día,

Mira, agregué una línea a tu código para que sea más fácil entender mi explicación:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string colores[5] = {"negro", "amarillo", "lila", "blanco", "azul"};
    

    for (int i = 0; i <= sizeof(colores) / sizeof(colores[0]) - 1; i++) {
        cout << sizeof(colores[i]) << endl;
        cout << i + 1 << " - " << colores[i] << "." << endl;
    }
}
```

La línea `cout << sizeof(colores[i]) << endl;` va a poner en la salida el tamaño de cada uno de los elementos de tu arreglo, así vas a darte cuenta que el valor es `32`

`sizeof` es un operador del compilador que regresa el tamaño en bytes de la representación de un objeto, esto es, el tamaño de memoria que tiene.

Dependiendo de la versión de la implementación de `string` que tengas (GCC’s libstdc++, Clang’s libc++, MSVC’s, etc...) el tamaño designado en memoria para un `string` puede ser diferente (32 bytes para las 3 implementaciones mencionadas).

Entonces lo que hace `sizeof(colores) / sizeof(colores[0])` es: primero calcula el tamaño total de tu arreglo `colores` y lo divide entre el tamaño de un elemento del arreglo (160/32 = 5) y luego le restas 1 para que tu ciclo itere desde 0 hasta 4. De hecho es una práctica común para asegurarte que tu ciclo (Bucle) no sobrepasa los límites de tu arreglo.

La razón por la que no funciona cuando cambias la condición del `for` a `sizeof(colores) - 1` es porque la comparación tiene `<=` si le quitas el `=` va a funcionar.

Answer (score 1):

> He leído que sizeof() devuelve el tamaño del objeto en bytes. Por eso, después se tiene que dividir ese número de bytes con el tamaño del elemento. Es esto lo que no acabo de entender. ¿Alguien me podría dar una explicación, si no más sencilla, más detallada?

El 97% de conceptos de programación se pueden entender con ejemplos de coches<sup>1</sup>; imagina que tienes un parquin y te pregunto "*¿cuántos coches caben en tu parquin?*". Para responder a esa pregunta necesitarás saber la longitud del parquin (`sizeof(parkin)`) y la longitud de los coches (`sizeof(coche)`).

Por lo que si tu parquin es de 30m y cada coche mide 3m te deberían caber 30/3=10 coches (un poco difícil aparcar pero teóricamente posible).